# DOL Data Dictionary Code Table

Tags: labor

I have reviewed the existing DOL data dictionary where certain codes are missing and it references the code table throughout the list. For example, the following table, osha_accident_injury in the description states cause of injury (code table OPER). The code table is referenced throughout the list but I need help finding this code table.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to edit your post and (i) explain all the acronyms  (DOL, OPER) which might be unfamiliar to someone who can help but doesn't speak your acronym language; (ii) provide links to any relevant website or webpage ... for example "the following table, osha_accident_injury" will be meaningless to anyone who can't find the table. ... and a link to the "DOL data dictionary"

Answer (score 0):

DOL is department of labor.  I have no idea what OPER is, I am guessing it's operational.  I tried multiples attempts to reach out to the department of labor for assistance and they won't or can't help. I know this Code Table exists because it is referenced throughout the data I have downloaded.

Comment: This should be an edit to the post, not a separate answer.